# Running into error when trying to run npm run dev command

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to follow a tutorial non javascript, so I'm trying to run webpack from node script but I've been getting this weird error, I've searched online but couldn't find the solution

the error:
C:\Users\Ahmad Usman\Desktop\9-forkify\webpack.config.js:2
const path = require("path");
^

below is the code (they are in different files though)

```js
// INDEX.JS FIle

import num from "./test";

console.log(`num: ${num}`);

// TEST.JS FILE

console.log('imported module');

export default 23;

// PACKAGE.JSON
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "Ahmad Usman",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.44.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  }
}

//WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

const path = require("path");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  mode: "development",
};
```

and here is a screenshot of my command line interface
[commandline screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYt47.png)

and [commandline screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7J8E.png)

Thanks

Comment: You are declaring same constant twice. `const path = require("path");` Voting to close as typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says :

```
SyntaxError: identifier 'path' has already been declared
```

So if you remove duplicate code it should work:

```
//WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

const path = require("path");
const path = require("path"); <-- declared twice

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
```

Comment: Thanks @Tajeshree, I didn't notice it